# Fire Alarm detect via MATLAB using FFT

Tags: matlab, fft

I want to take a wav. file and plot it in Time Domain and Frequency Domain on MATLAB.

I have this code thus far;

```
 [y,fs]=wavread('FireAlarm');
 %wavread=the function that is going to read the wav.file
 %y=samples
 %fs=sampling frequency
 %'FireAlarm'=wav file
 t=linespace(0,length(y)/fs,length(y));
 %linespace=the function that is going to create the time vector
 %0=start time
 %length(y)/fs=ending time
 %length(y)= number of samples in y
 plot(t,y)
 Nfft=1024;
 %Nfft=the length of fft
 f=linespace(0,fs,Nfft);
 %f= frequency vector
 %0=first frequency
 %fs=ending frequency
 %nfft=length of the frequency vector
 G=abs(fft(y,Nfft));
 %G= the fft of the samples y in 1024 points
 figure;plot(f(1:Nfft/2),G(1:Nfft/2)
```

Before I can even finish typing the first section, MATLAB tells there is an undefined function or variable 'wavread'.

Anyone know why this may be?

Comment: Google tells me `wavread` is now called `audioread`. Same functionality. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html

Comment: To add more to the above comment, `wavread` was removed in *MATLAB R2013a* and for the same (and probably more) functionality/ies, [**`audioread`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html) was introduced in *MATLAB R2012b* .